# Why does "clear()" work on Chrome's console, but not "log()"?

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools

The [console.clear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/clear) method clears the console if the console allows it. You can call it directly from Chrome's console by simply typing `clear()`, `console.clear()` or `window.clear()`.

The [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) method outputs a message to the web console. You **cannot** call it directly from Chrome's console by simply typing `log()`. You have to use `console.log()`.

I would understand this if `clear()` was a method listed inside the `window` object pointing to the method in the `console`, but it isn't listed when logging `console.log(window)` or `console.log(this)` in the console.

Why is `clear` directly accessible but `log` not?

Answer (score 2):

> You can call it directly from Chrome's console by simply typing `clear()`, but it's not a `window` method.

Yes, this [`clear()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#clear-function) is part of the [console utilities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/) which are accessible only from the console itself. It's not part of the [`console` object](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/api/) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console_API)).